# Grabbing Certain Values in Kendo Dropdown list

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Hello I am very new to Kendo UI and I am having issues getting certain value which is sent back from my controller in a Json format.

Json that is returned

[image]

My drop down list is binded to a view model

```
 var viewmodel = kendo.observable({
    region: "",
    id : "",
    } );

$("#engagementType").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "Select Region",
    dataTextField: "OfficeGroup",
    dataValueField: "OfficeGroupID",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "home/GetRegionList",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                method: "POST",
            }
        }
    },

    select: function(e){
        viewmodel.region = e.item[0].innerText;
        viewmodel.id = e.?????????????????? <<< cannot find the office group id
    }
});
```

Currently with the selected function I am able to get the office group names, however I when I am trying to get the Office group Id I am not seeing it coming in on "e" which is in my selected function.  Should I get the office Id another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI `DropDownList` does have functions `value()` and `text()`. Value function returns currently selected item dataValueField property value. Text function returns dataTextField property value.

On select function you can get values like this

```
select: function(e) {

    // selected value
    console.log(this.value());

    // selected text
    console.log(this.text());

    // selected item (ObservableObject)
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
    console.log(dataItem);
}
```